# Rust OR between two options

Tags: rust, operators

I want to know if its possible to perform an OR operation between two Options. Something like :

```
let a = Some(3);
let b = None;
let result = a || b;
```

Here I want the `result` variable to have either the value of `a` if it's a `Some` or the value of `b`.

I didn't find any documentation of this on Internet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Rust operands of  **Logical OR** (`||`) must be `bool`. So it is not possible to use it with `Option` or any other type.

But please see the `or` method from the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or) of `Option`.

> Returns the option if it contains a value, otherwise returns optb.

Your problem can be solved like this:

```rust
let a = Some(3);
let b = None;
let result = a.or(b); // result: Some(3)
```

If you want result as a `bool` you can use `is_some` or `is_none`

```rust
let result = a.or(b).is_some(); // true
let result = None.or(None).is_some(); // false
```

---

**OR_ELSE**

> Arguments passed to or are eagerly evaluated; if you are passing the
>   result of a function call, it is recommended to use or_else, which is
>   lazily evaluated.

You can also use `or_else` in a situation like this :

```rust
let a = Some(3);
let result = a.or(produce_option());
```

As you can see from the code whether your `a` is `Some` or `None` it will run `produce_option`, this may not be efficient in some(or many) circumstances.

```rust
let result = a.or_else(produce_option);
```

In here `produce_option` will only be called when `a` is `None`

---

**AND**

For **Logical AND** (`&&`) you can use `and` [method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and) of `Option`.

```rust
let a = None;
let b = Some(4);
let result = a.and(b); // result: None
```

For a lazy evaluation you can use **AND_THEN** like `OR_ELSE`.

---

**UNWRAP_OR**

`unwrap_or` or `unwrap_or_else` is also usable if you want to take the value inside the options while comparing. But this depends on the case, i am writing this as an example:

```rust
let a = None;
let b = None;
let x:i32 = a.unwrap_or(b.unwrap_or_default()); //Since `i32`'s default value is 0 `x` will be equal to 0

let a = None;
let b = Some(3);
let x:i32 = a.unwrap_or_else(||b.unwrap_or_default()); // `x` will be eqaul to 3
//using `unwrap_or_else` might be a better idea, because of the lazy evaluation.
```

---

**Note :** This answer focused on `Option` but these are all applicable for `Result` objects which have **same error type**.